# Circuit problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries

[image]

Hello, can someone please help me on this problem?

Question: calculate the potentials at A and B.

The solution says that they are both 12V "due to symmetry" but I have no idea what is the thought process behind this. I was able to do it the long way by setting up currents and using kirchhoffs current law to form a system of equations, but clearly there is an easier way I'm missing out on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless a reference value for potential is mentioned, there is no way to calculate the absolute value of the potential at A and B.

---

The wire joining A and B is ideal, that is, it has no resistance. From the definition of resistance $\Delta V = IR$, the potential difference between points A and B is zero. Hence the potentials at A and B are the same.

As the resistances labelled $R_1$ and $R_3$ are between the same potential difference, they are in parallel. The same argument can be applied to resistances labelled $R_2$ and $R_4$. The two sets of resistances are in series.

---

What is "symmetric" about this problem, is that the equivalent resistance of both sets of resistances are the same. Hence, the terminal potential difference of the battery ($24V$) is split equally across the two sets ; $12V$ each, which represent the potential *difference* between *each terminal* of the battery and the points A and B

Hope this helps.